# How can I generate Gabor patterns with specified contrasts in Matlab, and save them as pictures?

Tags: matlab, contrast

I need to create pictures with a specific Gabor pattern, with different levels of contrast - from 0% to 100%.

I know there is a "Gabor" function in Matlab, but I did not find a way to define the Gabor's contrast.

I know there is also a PsychToolbox function that creates a Gabor texture on the screen (Screen('DrawTexture', windowPtr, gaborid...), but I do not need to present the Gabors on screen, I need to save bitmap pictures, and I do not know how to capture pictures presented on a running PsychToolbox screen (so a function\code that captures the screen and saves it would be appreciated as well).

Thank you!

Genie

Answer (score 0):

```
% Create the Gabor filter
F = gabor(20, 45);
F = real(F.SpatialKernel);
% Save the contrast-adjusted images
for contrast = linspace(0, 1, 5)
    imwrite(((F * contrast) + 1) * 0.5, sprintf('gabor_%g.png', contrast));
end
```